# Pandas converts string-typed JSON value to INT

Tags: json, pandas

I have list of objects as JSON. Each object has two properties: *id(string)* and *arg(number)*.

When I use `pandas.read_json(...)`, the resulting DataFrame has the id interpreted as number as well, which causes problems, since information is lost.

```
import pandas as pd

json = '[{ "id" : "1", "arg": 1 },{ "id" : "1_1", "arg": 2}, { "id" : "11", "arg": 2}]'

df = pd.read_json(json)
```

I'd expect to have a DataFrame like this:

```
     id     arg  
0   "1"      1
1   "1_1"    2
2   "11"     2
```

I get

```
     id     arg  
0     1      1
1    11      2
2    11      2
```

and suddenly, the once unique id is not so unique anymore.

How can I tell pandas to stop doing that?

*My search so far only yielded results, where people where trying to achive the opposite - having columns of string beeing interpreted as numbers. I totally don't want to achive that in this case!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dtype` parameter for preventing cast `id` to numbers:

```
df = pd.read_json(json, dtype={'id':str})

print (df)
    id  arg
0    1    1
1  1_1    2
2   11    2


print (df.dtypes)
id     object
arg     int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

If you set the `dtype` parameter to `False`, `read_json` will not infer the types automatically:

```py
df = pd.read_json(json, dtype=False)
```